# When the shift of Monkhorst-Pack k-points method in QE or VASP OR or anyothers is set to zero?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I have read [the paper of Monkhorst-Pack method](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.13.5188) and the C-C method,and in my understanding the shift of k-points in Monkhorst-Pack method with the parameter Ni which chose to be even, is to avoid the gamma point or the k-points on the boundary,and the point of gamma and the points on the boundary is high symmetry point,so there is degeneracy,and the degeneracy means extreme points,and the M-P method is take the mean value,so it should be avoid .but sometimes the shift just set to 0(just like in the QE scf namelist ),and if i do this,the gamma point and the points on the boundary which the M-P method should avoid is just take into account,what the meaning of it?